# Audio Connection Issues - Recording

Tags: piano, recording

I have a Yamaha P45 that has a midi to USB connection, Abelton Live 11, Sapphire Solo Studio and I use Playground Sessions APP on a Dell Laptop to learn and practice piano.  I can get the piano connected to the computer and Ableton Live and record ok. I cannot seem to get it to be able to simultaneously record the Playground Sessions backtrack and the piano sound.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why not just record separately and then align the two tracks in Ableton?

Comment: I can try that, but will have to record twice.  The backing track, then the actual playing.  I just thought it would sound better to record them together.  :)  Thank you for the suggestion.